# Terminating a python thread from within based on a timer

Tags: python, multithreading

I have tried to solve this problem through multiple forums and still have not got a solution to the answer. 
I'll try to be as specific as possible as to what I am looking for. 
I have a use case where I need to have a thread terminate itself after a certain time out. I do not want to use .join(timeout=x) from the main thread because that as I understand does not terminate the thread. I want this timed event to be realized within the thread and it should do some clean up and updates before it terminates itself.
JFYI: I can't use a loop wothin the run method to check for a state. My need is that the target function will be called within the run method.

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.timer = Timer(5.0, self.timeout)

    def run(self):
        self.timer.start()
        # call the target function which runs

     def timeout(self):
          # timeout code
          # If timeout has been reached then thread should do some internal cleanup and terminate thread here.
```

Comment: Threads can only be terminated cooperatively. If whatever function you are calling doesn't have a mechanism for stopping it, then you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `eventlet.timeout`. The `target_function` below is the main logic in the `Thread.run` block. When time is up, it throws a pre-defined exception. You can add your internal cleanup logic block in the `cleanup` function.

```
from eventlet.timeout import Timeout
from eventlet import sleep


class TimeoutError(Exception):
    pass


def target_function(seconds=10):
    print("Run target functions ...")
    for i in range(seconds, -1, -1):
        print("Count down: " + str(i))
        sleep(1)


def cleanup():
    print("Do cleanup ...")

timeout = Timeout(seconds=5, exception=TimeoutError)
try:
    target_function(20)
except TimeoutError:
    cleanup()
finally:
    print("Timeout ...")
    timeout.cancel()
```

I hope it meets your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Theresa. Let me try this out. This may work for me. So I presume in this case the thread terminates within itself?

Comment: Does this only start executing the target function after the timer has reached? I wanted the thread to start executing the target function and terminate itself when the timer is reached. Is there a way I can get this working for that?